# How can I make C# foreach with nested subtitles?

Tags: c#, linq, foreach

Hello I'm a beginner and I am working with **ASP.NET with MVC5**.

I want to make an **IEnumerable<> Food-Menu-Pricelist with nested titles (Courses) in 1 foreach** so I can Create or Edit a new string (CourseName) with the CRUD-Operations I have made with Entity Framework.

I will **embed a picture in the link below** which I made semi/hardcoded and like you can see in the **code below** the titles are hardcoded.

*Preview of result I want to reach:*
[image: preview of result I want to reach]

I have 2 models:

1. Course.cs = the title with Property string: *CourseName*
2. Dish.cs = and the list with Property string: *DishName*

Is there a way I can put this table **in 1 foreach** in that way that I also can Edit the title with the CRUD-Operations with te model I have defined?

I already tried a lot to reach that. Anyway this was my first question on Stackoverflow..

```
    @model IEnumerable<Project_Lameau.Models.Dish>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Suggestie</h2>

<table class="table">
    @foreach (var item in Model.Where(d => d.CourseName.Contains("Suggestie")))
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@item.DishName</td>
            <td class="text-right">@item.Price</td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
<hr />


<h2>Salade</h2>

<table class="table">
    @foreach (var item in Model.Where(d => d.CourseName.Contains("Salade")))
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@item.DishName</td>
            <td class="text-right">@item.Price</td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
<hr />


<h2>Voorgerecht</h2>

<table class="table">
    @foreach (var item in Model.Where(d => d.CourseName.Contains("Voorgerecht")))
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@item.DishName</td>
            <td class="text-right">@item.Price</td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
<hr />


<h2>Hoofd Vlees</h2>

<table class="table">
    @foreach (var item in Model.Where(d => d.CourseName.Contains("Hoofd Vlees")))
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@item.DishName</td>
            <td class="text-right">@item.Price</td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
<hr />


<h2>Hoofd Vis</h2>

<table class="table">
    @foreach (var item in Model.Where(d => d.CourseName.Contains("Hoofd Vis")))
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@item.DishName</td>
            <td class="text-right">@item.Price</td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
<hr />


<h2>Vega</h2>

<table class="table">
    @foreach (var item in Model.Where(d => d.CourseName.Contains("Vega")))
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@item.DishName</td>
            <td class="text-right">@item.Price</td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Comment: What does the `Dish` class look like?

Comment: public class Dish
    {   public int Id { get; set; }
        public int CourseId { get; set; }      
        public string DishName { get; set; }
        public decimal? Price { get; set; }

       
        public Course Course { get; set; }
    }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your top level `foreach` would be something like

```
foreach (var courseGroup in Model.GroupBy(m => m.CourseName))
```

And each item would be:

```
<h2>courseGroup.Key</h2>

<table class="table">
    @foreach (var item in courseGroup)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@item.DishName</td>
            <td class="text-right">@item.Price</td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

However, you can organise your data a bit more, so if you defined your classes (and tables in your database), as something like this:

```
public class Course
{
    public string CourseName { get; set; }
    public List<Dish> Dishes { get; set; }
}

public class Dish
{
    public string DishName { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

Then your code becomes a lot simpler:

```
foreach (var course in Model) //or Model.Courses - up to you
```

And each item would be:

```
<h2>course.CourseName</h2>

<table class="table">
    @foreach (var item in course.Dishes)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@item.DishName</td>
            <td class="text-right">@item.Price</td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Rob for your help. I appreciate it!
I choose for the first option. 
I had to extend the Controller code with a lamda-expression `.Include(m => m.Course)` because I needed to include the property (CourseName) of the first class (Course.cs). The Dish class had already Lookup property `public Course Course { get; set; }`) So I changed the top level foreach in `@foreach (var courseGroup in Model.GroupBy(m => m.Course.CourseName))` and then everything worked out fine.

The second option did not work. I think because of the demodata that is related between the two classes Course.cs an Dish.cs that has a CourseId property.

Cheers!